# using an each-ready function for only one element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, you can do something like

```
[1,2,3].each(my_func)
```

and inside my_func, that don't receive arguments, you can reference the current number with the variable `this`.

now let's say I want to call my_func again for only one element. I could do this way:

```
[1].each(my_func)
```

Is there a better way to call that function again for only one element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes; there is a much easier way:

```
myFunc(1);
```

If you want to pass it as `this`, it's [still easy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
myFunc.call(1);
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! The second one is what I was looking for. (will accept in 12 minutes)

Comment: NB: `typeof this === "object"` even if you pass a primitive